# Clubs, in which people are dancing to music with the purpose of dropping their weight

Tags: terminology

How do they refer in English to those clubs, in which people are dancing to music with the purpose of dropping some weight? Is the word "shaping" common in that sense? Could those clubs be called "shaping clubs" or are there some better terms for that?

(I don't mean fitness centers, in which people do physical exercises instead of dancing to music)

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean [Zumba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zumba), or something like it, since you explicitly say you don't mean fitness centers.

Comment: @mathewb - Does "fitness center" imply dancing activity, too?

Comment: Not exactly. A fitness center would be like a gym - maybe a weight room, some treadmills and such in another area, and it may have separate studio rooms for classes such as Zumba, pilates, yoga, etc. The fitness center is a more generally purpose place, but people may go there specifically for that dance/exercise class, and not to lift weights or run on a treadmill.

Comment: @mathewb - So, is it possible to come up with something less specific than Zumba and yet not as general as "fitness center". What would you yourself say if you were involved in that kind of classes, and, while you were leaving for one of such classes, one of your family members asked, "Where are you going?"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Body) shaping is a type of aerobic exercise, however, its association to dance is loose, at best. So I don't think that is the correct term.

The best general suggestion that I can make is to call it a [dance fitness class](http://www.latimes.com/health/la-he-dance-workouts-20151031-story.html). Google it, and you'll find plenty of places offering it. It's a very literal term, so it may not be what you're looking for.

[Zumba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zumba) is a very popular type of dance fitness class. It may be popular enough that you could use it in place of "dance fitness class," and your audience would understand the gist of it, even if it wasn't actually Zumba. [Barre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barre_(exercise)) is another, but it is focused on ballet dancing. There are plenty of other general categories and proprietary names for specific dance fitness classes, with varying degrees of popularity, such as pole dancing, Jazzercise, and Bhangra.